# Is that a common way to change the start script(www) to be async?

Tags: node.js, express

I need to call an app to get a `secret key` which are used for encrypting data, I used `mongoose plugin` to implement that, so I should call the app before defining models which would happen when requiring `app.js`.

This is my solution, I changed the `bin/www` to be async so that I could use `async / await`.

```
(async () => {
    const secretKey = await getXxx();
    global.secretKey = secretKey;
    const app = require('./app');
    ...
})();
```

I just think async / await is more readable, so I don't want to use `Promise.then`, is there anything wrong?

Comment: Sure, if it works, it works, but if that's your *only* `await` at that level, I'm not seeing the benefit of avoiding `.then`. It might be a good idea to pass `secretKey` around rather than to make it global

Comment: @CertainPerformance I just think `async / await` is more readable, I worry about there will be too many `Promise.then`.

Comment: That's why I said `if that's your only await`. If you have more than one, then `await` *does* save you the extra syntax noise of multiple `.then`s (but only a single `.then` is just as fine, and perhaps even better, than an IIFE with only a single `await` in it... IMO. Opinion-based)

Comment: To add, its a good practice to have `async-await` in a `try/catch` to handle thrown errors from the promise.